# Dialogflow NodeJS library issue

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on a dialogflow POC where I'm trying to invoke the **v2** API provided by DialogFlow. While trying the NodeJS code example provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api), I'm getting the below error

```
{ Error: EHOSTUNREACH undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.38.172:80 - Local (192.168.0.103:51468)
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/devuser/Development/workspaces/df-poc/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/Users/devuser/Development/workspaces/df-poc/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/devuser/Development/workspaces/df-poc/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:75:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  details:
   'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.38.172:80 - Local (192.168.0.103:51468)',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} } }
```

I have imported `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and point the environment variable to the credentials. The invocation works fine if I try the REST API route with the Authorization header.
Kindly let me know if there is something which I'm missing here.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Code is available here .. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api. Just scroll down, NodeJS

Comment: My code is the copy paste of the sample code which is available there

Comment: Same error, along with a projectId reference error

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer or close the thread as the question was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This means `EHOST` (the remote host of the files you are requesting) are unreachable. They are either down, or your computer cannot access them due to some other restriction, such as location, which can be solved with a VPN.

Comment: If you access "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" in your browser, it doesn't work either even with an internet connection

Comment: @Apps Doesn't work for me either. I think it's down.

Comment: @Apps wait an hour or so and try again. If it doesn't work then, it has most likely either been taken down, or is heavily over-trafficked right now, in which case you will just have to keep retrying. No way around it.

Comment: I had been trying this for over 4 hours :-(. No luck so far.

Comment: @Apps then it is most likely either under maintenance, over trafficked, or just removed. Nothing to be done about it on your end.

Comment: Your computer is obviously successfully sending a request, but not receiving anything in response. That is a problem on the server side.

Comment: If it was a problem on your side, it would say `connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)` but it shows your local out on port 51468, so it isn't blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Will a Google service go down for so long? Suprising

Comment: If it is under maintenance or taken down, yes.

Comment: There is no reference to this endpoint URL in that code or library. So it has to be the response from another call. Which means google themselves is giving this URL as a response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201111/discussion-between-death-waltz-and-apps).

Comment: @Apps exactly, which means it cannot be your problem. You might as well close this thread unless you really think there is something else